# Meteor-Up failures on 2 different servers

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I am experiencing failure every time I try to deploy to either an AWS/EC2 instance or a Digital Ocean droplet.  With the EC2 instance I am using a pem file and with the droplet I am using password access.  There were a lot of hoops to jump through to get through the mup setup, but that is finally successful on both instances.  It's the mup deploy that fails on the Invoking deployment process: step.

Here's my mup.json for the droplet:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "notmypassword"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
      //"pem": "/users/alex/dropbox/awspems/projectmanager.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.33 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.35",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "projectmanager",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/users/alex/dropbox/projectmanager",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://xx.xx.xx.xx"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 30
}
```

The following messages appear whether in the EC2 instance or the droplet instance:

```
Claire-MacAir-7:projectmanager alex$ mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Building Started: /users/notmyusername/dropbox/projectmanager

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'projectmanager' (linux)
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Uploading bundle
[xx.xx.xx.xx] ✔ Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setting up Environment Variables
[xx.xx.xx.xx] ✔ Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Invoking deployment process
[xx.xx.xx.xx] ✘ Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    ir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.35',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/projectmanager/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    stop: Unknown instance:
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    App did not pick up! Please check app logs.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    LE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node: Finished
      COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
    make: Leaving directory `/opt/projectmanager/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/projectmanager/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
    ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
    ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
    ├── supports-color@0.2.0
    ├── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
    └── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
    └── type-of@2.0.1

    source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
    └── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)

    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    connected
    projectmanager start/running, process 11786
    Waiting for 30 seconds while app is booting up
    Checking is app booted or not?
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed TaskList: Deploy app 'projectmanager' (linux)
```

The project works perfectly with no errors on my localhost.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, Alex Adams

---

### And the solution is:

The mup logs showed that it didn't like a path designated for a folder to hold uploaded files.  I changed the app to use GridFS, thus storing the files in the database.  The app deploys correctly now.

Comment: could you please run` mup logs` to see the what happened? just to be sure you run `mup setup`?

Comment: Thanks Ethaan.  The log told me it didn't like a designated folder path for storing uploaded files.  I simply changed the app to use GridFS instead and now it deploys correctly.  It was something I intended to do anyway.  A good argument for keeping everything in the database, no paths or permissions needed outside the app.